# Access is denied error when executing create_tf_record.py

Tags: tensorflow

Receiving below error while executing the create_tf_record.py file from the link

https://towardsdatascience.com/custom-object-detection-using-tensorflow-from-scratch-e61da2e10087

.UnknownError: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/envs/py36/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/annotations/ : Access is denied.
; Input/output error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please could you add some more details to your question.

Comment: When debugged the code, found that the error is with respect to code label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(FLAGS.label_map_path) where i've defined flags.DEFINE_string('label_map_path', 'C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/envs/py36/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow/models/annotations/', 'label_map.pbtxt') ....Any help will be highly appreciated.